# Pulling out data from a line of text in C++ using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have a text file in the format:

```
number tab word tab word tab junk
number tab word tab word tab junk
number tab word tab word tab junk
number tab word tab word tab junk
number tab word tab word tab junk
```

For each line I'd like to put the number in a uint32_t, then the two words into strings and then ignore the rest of the line.  I could do this by loading the file into memory and then working through it a byte at a time, but I'm convinced that a lovely regex could do it for me.  Any ideas?

I'm working in C++ using #include  in Xcode - this is a commandline tool so there's no real output, I'm just storing the data to compare with other data.

Comment: as you mention `c++` and `regex` is this a `c++11` question or do you use some third-party library?

Comment: why not just `file >> num >> word1 >> word2`? Then you can either read the junk in and ignore it, or use `.Ignore()`...

Comment: post an example of the desired output.

Comment: I've updated the question - I'll have a go at file >> num >> word1 >> word2 - clever stuff!

Comment: There's still outputs!  Just because you're not sending stuff to std::out doesn't mean that you're not expecting the data in a certain format, outputting it, storing it somewhere.  These can all be thought of as outputs.  Your output in this case is the data that you're storing, and the format that you'd like it in...

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned in the question I'd like a uint32_t and two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern bool DoStuff(unsigned n, 
                    const std::string &s0, 
                    const std::string &s1);

bool ProcessFile(const std::string &sFileName)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(sFileName);
    if (!ifs)
        return false;

    while (ifs)
    {
        unsigned n;
        std::string s0, s1;
        ifs >> n >> s0 >> s1;
        if (ifs.bad() || !DoStuff(n, s0, s1))
            return false;
        ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return !ifs.bad();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt, you can use this simple regex:

```
(?im)^(\d+)\t([a-z]+)\t([a-z]+)
```

It captures the number in Group 1, the first word in Group 2, and the second word in Group 3.

To retrieve them from Groups 1, 2 and 3, I am not sure of your the exact C++ syntax, but this code stub give one idea of how to iterate over the matches and groups. Note that in this case we don't care about the overall matches, just the capturing groups.

```
try {
    TRegEx RegEx("(?im)^(\\d+)\t([a-z]+)\t([a-z]+)", TRegExOptions() << roIgnoreCase << roMultiLine);
    TMatch Match = RegEx.Match(SubjectString);
    while (Match.Success) {
        for (int i = 1; i < Match.Groups.Count; i++) {
            TGroup Group = Match.Groups[i];
            if (Group.Success) {
                // matched text: Group.Value
                // match start: Group.Index
                // match length: Group.Length
            } 
        }
        Match = Match.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ERegularExpressionError *ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```